# Add AD group to SharePoint Online using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, rest, groups, ad

Is it possible to add an AD group into SharePoint. I've created a user group in the Office 365 portal, which appears to be stored in AD. Is there a way of searching for this AD group and adding it.

SharePoint allows you to do this through the UI but I cant see it anywhere in the API. If not is there away of importing all of the groups?

Comment: check this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/create-a-new-site-group-in-sharepoint-2013-online-using-rest/

Comment: They dont appear in the siteusers or groups, they only appear there when you add the through the UI. They start with c:0-.f|rolemanager|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EnsureUser works
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819(v=office.15).aspx#bk_WebEnsureUser

Just pass the GroupName and you can get the principalId of the group

Answer (score 0):

It might not be te most elegant solution, but this will get them into which ever group you put as $group. If your AD is on-prem follow [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151800.aspx#BKMK_InstallDirSyncTool) first. If they are already synced to your Azure AD, then just run the below code.

```
function Connect-SPOSite() {

param (

    $admuser = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com",

    $admsite = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"

) 

if ((Get-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell).Count -eq 0) {

    Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking

}

$cred = Get-Credential $admuser

Connect-SPOService -Url $admsite -Credential $cred

} 


$site = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com"
$users = Get-Content Path to users.txt
$group = the group you want them in
foreach ($user in $users)
{
try
{
    Add-SPOUser -Site $site -LoginName $user -Group $group
    Write-Output "Successfully added user $user, $_ to group"
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Error adding user $user, $_ to group"
}
}
```