# add existing AzureAD group to sharepoint online site with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have an problem with adding existing Azure AD groups to SharePoint online.
What am I trying to do, I’m creating 50+ sites and break the site inheritance.
then I like to add existing AzureAD groups to the SharePoint online site

there are a lot of sites that explaine how to create a new group and add that to the site and how to add users to a group but I haven’t found an site that explains how to add an existing group to a site.

I looked at this site but this is adding users to an group
[Add AD group to SharePoint Online using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125170/add-ad-group-to-sharepoint-online-using-rest-api)

the title of the site sounded good

I know how to do this on-prem but in the cloud there is where i have a problem

Hope someone knows the answer

Comment: do these groups have email address ? do you want to add the Azure AD group to a SharePoint group ?

Comment: I like to add an Azure AD group to an site, not to an SharePoint group
if i add an Azure AD group to an Sharepoint group than I have two groups for the same site.

if possible I want to skip the Sharepoint group

Answer (score 1):

We did the following when adding AD groups via C#:

```
var group = ctx.Web.EnsureUser($"c:0t.c|tenant|{groupid}");
item.RoleAssignments.Add(group, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) {contribute});
```

Where groupid was the object identifier of the AD group.  If you import the SharePoint Client libraries to PowerShell, you should be able to refactor this so that you can use it.

Comment: I don't get this to work

I added these two files to the powershell script but no luck
Add-Type -Path "C:\~\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\~\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

also I have to say that my C# knowledge is not that great, PowerShell is a lot better

Answer (score 0):

I already faced this situation, the trick is to create a SP group let's name it (All AD Groups), and let's suppose we already created our AD groups (for example: ADG1, ADG2 ...etc)

in sharepoint the AD groups are considered users (not SP groups), so all you need to do is to add this AD groups to the SP group created above "All AD Groups", and you will see that your AD groups are automatically add to your site collection.

Comment: BOULAGIA Did you manage to do it from code? I have the same situation but I have trouble when adding the groups using code.

Comment: Never tried it, can you illustrate it more ?

Comment: Well I fixed it using some of the code in this answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/287058/add-ad-groups-to-sharepoint-online-group-using-csom/287107?noredirect=1#comment305059_287107

But the mistake was mine to try to add Office365 groups at the first place. It is working perfectly fine if only security groups are used