# Add AD Groups to Sharepoint Online Group using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, active-directory, pnp-powershell, office-365-groups

I have the following situation:

AD:

- Users
- Groups

Sharepoint:

- Groups

The hole point is to add both the users and the groups from AD to Sharepoint. I got adding the users to work using the following code:

```
    User adUser = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(ad.LogOnName);
    ctx.Load(adUser);
    gc.Users.AddUser(adUser);
    ctx.Load(gc, x => x.Users);
```

Where the `LogOnName` is the **User Principal Name** of the user. When adding the groups as `LogOnName` is used the group name.

Any suggestions where I am mistaken wehn adding the groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my sample tested code for your reference:

```
User group = ctx.Web.EnsureUser("SecurityGroup");
ctx.Load(gc);
User addUser=gc.Users.AddUser(group);
ctx.Load(addUser);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Update:

For the Office 365 group, use the group email in the code:

```
User group = ctx.Web.EnsureUser("group@tenant.onmicrosoft.com");
```

Comment: thanks for your response. That will work for the security group but at the moment i add the Office365 group i get an exception: `the collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute`. I am looping trough all of my Sharepoint groups and adding users/groups dynamically.

Comment: For the Office365 group, you could use the group email in the code.

Comment: Thank you! It is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Adding an AD group to an existing SharePoint group CSOM:

```
           //Ensure AD group Name 
            User adGroup = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(@"domain\ADgroupName");
            clientContext.Load(adGroup);

            GroupCollection groupColl = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups;
            Group spgroup = groupColl.GetByName("SPVisitors"); //SharePoint Existing Group
            spgroup.Users.AddUser(adGroup);
            clientContext.Load(spgroup);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: thanks for your response! Just a question....where i can find the `domain` or it just have to say `"domain\ADgroupName"`